# View of Constraints and Decision Variables in Pyomo

Tags: python, solver, constraint, pyomo

I have just attempted to construct my first Pyomo model.

However, I was unable to locate any documentation that shows how to view constraints, decision variables.

As my model is big, I need to see that they are created and indexed correctly from time-to-time before proceeding further.

May I ask if anyone has chanced upon such documentation or have devised any ingenious method to do so within the confines of Python or Pyomo syntax?

Thank you!

Comment: Not too familiar with Pyomo, but wouldn’t model.write(“model.lp”) write your model to an lp file (which is very readable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After defining your model by putting the following statement in your code (wherever you want before or after solve command) your model with all the objects has been printed:

```
model.pprint()
```

If you like to print constraints or variables individually:

```
model.cons1.pprint()  # For entire ConstraintList
print(model.cons2[i].expr)  # For only one index of ConstraintList
model.write() # To write the model into a file using .nl format
```

Assuming that `model` is the model that you defined and `cons1` and `cons2` are two ConstraintsList in that model.

Comment: Thanks again for your generosity!

Comment: @Mike you are welcome...